# How do I add a function stored in a string to a jquery .click event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a generic table generator where I can tell it the function to call in the onclick event of each cell. The function is then defined somewhere else on the page.

The problem is I cannot get the page to evaluate the function at the right moment. I want it to convert my string to a function when it is building the DOM not when it fires the click event. Maybe this is not possible in Javascript/JQuery?

A simplified version of the code I originally wrote server-side in C# is:

```
string functionCall = "DoSomething(4);";
TableCell detailCell = new TableCell();
detailCell.Attributes.Add("onClick", functionCall);
functionCall = "DoSomething(5);";
detailCell = new TableCell();
detailCell.Attributes.Add("onClick", functionCall);
```

This then worked when it was rendered as html in the browser. It turned into:

```
 function DoSomething(p)
 {
      alert(p);
 }

<td onclick="DoSomething(4)"></td>
<td onclick="DoSomething(5)"></td>
```

I want to replicate this functionality in Javascript.

If I do:

```
var functionCall = 'DoSomething(4);';
$('#detailCell').attr('onclick', functionCall);
```

it won't fire the event in IE7 for some reason but fires it in Chrome.

If I do:

```
var functionCall = 'DoSomething(4);';
$('#detailCell1').click(function () { eval(functionCall); });
functionCall = 'DoSomething(5);';
$('#detailCell2').click(function () { eval(functionCall); });
```

then it doesn't change functionCall to a piece of text when the click event is added. Instead it evals functionCall WHEN the cell is clicked. This means the value of functionCall is now wrong.

e.g. it always does DoSomething(5) even if I click on detailCell1 because that was the last value of functionCall.

If I do:

```
var functionCall = 'DoSomething(4);';
$('#detailCell1').click(eval(functionCall));
```

it runs the function in functionCall immediately when adding the click event rather than when it is clicked.

I hope this makes some sense as it is difficult to explain.

Basically I just want to be able to do

```
<td onclick="any javascript I feel like storing in a string"></td>
```

using JQuery.

Is this even possible?

This is my first ever post on stackoverflow so please be gentle...

Comment: Why do you need it like a string?

Comment: Why do you ask why he needs it like a string?

Comment: Why can't you call the function directly.

Comment: Such approach is strange and I'm not sure why function call must be stored in a string variable. That could be done in much better way without any strings. But maybe there is something that makes it easier to use strings like OP tries.

Comment: @jAndy because understanding the task makes for a better solution could be one viable answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
var functionCall = 'DoSomething(4);';

$('#detailCell1').click((function (code) {
  return function () { 
     eval(code); 
  };
}(functionCall)));
```

What happens here is that you capture the string at the time that you create the handler by assigning it to the parameter 'code'.

In your current scenario the click handler uses the value of the string at the time it is clicked and not at the time the handler is created.

This is called a closure!

```
(function (code) {
  return function () { 
     eval(code); 
  };
}(functionCall));
```

The functionCall value is assigned to the code parameter.
Now when you change functionCall the code parameter still refers to the old value.

Comment: Wow this works but I don't really understand it. If only I could write lovely compiled C# in a browser!  I will do some research into closure. Thanks a lot for your time Bart.

Comment: @user2010602 instead of emitting the function call as a string use a function literal. It makes the code faster and easier to read. There's no reason why you should have that extra step of evaluating a constant (your function call)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why function call should be in string. As I can see, you have many cells that should fire one function with different params for each cell.

In this case I would do next:

```
TableCell detailCell = new TableCell();
detailCell.Attributes.Add("class", "detailCell");
detailCell.Attributes.Add("data-num", "4");

detailCell = new TableCell();
detailCell.Attributes.Add("class", "detailCell");
detailCell.Attributes.Add("data-num", "5");
```

And than, somewhere in js:

```
$(function() {
    $(".detailCell").click(function(){
        DoSomething($(this).data("num"));
    });
})
```

`class` on table cell is needed in order to easily assign  click handler to all detail cells, so you do not need to write something like:

```
$('#detailCell1').click(function () { DoSomething(4); });
$('#detailCell2').click(function () { DoSomething(5); });
```

This `detailCell.Attributes.Add("data-num", "5");` allows to put number that should be used as a parameter for `DoSomething`. You can see it being taken in this row:       `DoSomething($(this).data("num"));` `jQuery.data` function is being used. and `this` will point to an element being clicked. 
`$(function() {})` - this is a shorthand for `jQuery.ready` function. Using it you can guaranty that code inside that function will be executed when page is ready for use.

Comment: Thanks FAngel, using the id attribute for that was going to be my backup method if I couldn't find a way to do it the way I originally envisaged.

Answer (score 0):

instead of first creating it as a string and then trying to evaluate that string you can simply create a function value (functions are object too in JS)

so instead of

```
var functionCall = 'DoSomething(4);';
$('#detailCell1').click(eval(functionCall));
```

do

```
$('#detailCell1').click(function(e){DoSomething(4);});
```

this creates a new function for every click. (In your case you could omit the e parameter, it's simply there to make any changes that requires it easier

if you have a set of parameters you are passing you can create a factory method

```
var doSomethingFactory = function(num){
    return function(e) { DoSomething(num);};
}
$('#detailCell1').click(doSomethingFactory(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you have to call different function with different arguments.To achieve this you are generating string and try to call those function by using eval() function. Let us do these as follows.

1.Just pass those functioncalls string as array, So that on load your javascript code look like as follows,

```
var functioncalls = ['DoSomething(1)','DoSomethingMore(1,2)','DoDifferent("hello world")'];
```

2.Then loop your function call array in javascript and assign them to different click event, To avoid complexity, I assume you selector are #detailCell0,#detailCell1,#detailCell2 and so on. Then your code look like as follows,

```
$(function(){
      functioncalls.forEach(function(functioncall,index){
          $("detailCell"+index).click(function(){ 
                eval(functioncall);
           })
      });
    })
```

Note: There are lot of ways to do this.